# The type or namespace Http does not exist in the namespace Flurl

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library, flurl

Starting a new Portable Class Library project, I've added the [Flurl.Http NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/), which appears to have also brought down all it's dependancies, as expected.

However when I add the using Flurl.Http directive and some simple code such as

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;

public class ClientRepository
{
    public async Task<string> Connect()
    {
        var result = await "http://example.com"
            .AppendPathSegment("/login")
            .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { username = "you", password = "password" }).ReceiveJson();
        return result.token;
    }
}
```

I get the compile error

> The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Flurl' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What's odd that intellisense has no problem recognizing the .Http namespace, or the extension methods (PostUrlEncodedAsync)

What could I be missing from this most basic of PCL projects?

Perhaps my package.config file would be of value, so here it is as well:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Flurl" version="1.0.5" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Flurl.Http" version="0.4.1" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="PCLStorage" version="0.9.6" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
</packages>
```

Comment: I've just created a PCL and imported Flurl and compiled without issues. However my packages.config is NOT the same as yours. While it has the same id and versions, the targetframework is "portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80" so I suggest that is where your problem lies. You might want to edit your question to detail exactly what project types/IDE/extensions you are using as I dont have the option to target that framework out of the box in VS Ultimate 2013 Update 4.

Comment: I should also add when I added Flurl to a Console app it specifically asked me to add a reference to System.Net.Http. Now when I Google "Mono System.Net.Http" I get a slew of result re:Mono and Xamarin incompatibilities with System.Net.Http. Newer posts suggest this has been rectified but it was an issue circa 2013 so that is where I'd start looking for trouble. Be surprised if verbose mode in output window doesn't give you the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce using the combination of target platforms gleaned from your packages.config (very helpful). The problem appears to be with Silverlight 5. This was working at one point; my hunch is that support was dropped for it in one of the dependent libraries, though I've not yet confirmed that.

At any rate, if you can get by without SL5 support (and maybe you can't), I've confirmed that a new PCL targeting all the others that Flurl.Http is documented to support does build with your code:

[image: Flurl.Http PCL support]

(Side note: I've run into issues trying to change PCL targets in existing projects - you might save yourself some headaches by starting with a clean slate.)

My apologies for any inconvenience. I'll update the list of supported targets in the [docs](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/installation/). I welcome any suggestions/pull requests to get it working with SL5.

Comment: Just a note I wasn't able to turn off Silverlight5 unless I selected Windows 8  but once I did that yes I was able to get it to compile.  My primary target is Xamarin.iOS although I will say I was hoping to use Silverlight as well.  I'll be interested to hear if it can be sorted out.